# How to change environment variables non-persistently in vbs

Tags: windows, vbscript

```
Set Shell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set Environment=Shell.Environment("User")
Environment("Path")=Environment("Path")&"C:\"
```

I want to change environment variables of the wscript.exe process that runs the script, affecting it and its subprocesses only. The code above is not what I want, because it changes HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment registry setting which affects every new process. In other words, I need the counterpart of the `set` command in cmd.exe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change `process` environment:

```vb
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    With .Environment("process")
        .Item("path") = .Item("path") & ";C:\"
    End With
    .Run "wscript.exe ""C:\test\another.vbs"""
End With
```